# Java Swing Timer stops running automatically

Tags: java, swing, timer

I'm trying to implement a Swing timer that runs forever (or until it's told to stop). I am not sure why, but the following code will execute for about 8 seconds and then stop on its own.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SwingTimer {

private int count;

public SwingTimer() {
   count = 0;
   final int delay = 1000;
   ActionListener l = new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         System.out.println("Count: " + (++count));
      }
   };

   new Timer(delay,l).start();

   try {
      Thread.sleep(2000);
   } catch(InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
   }
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       new SwingTimer();

    }
}
```

However, in an example I downloaded, the code is pretty much exactly the same as the above, except that the delay is 500 milliseconds instead of 1000, and that timer will run for a seemingly indefinite amount of time. When I change the 500 to 1000 in that example, it performs in the same way as the above code.

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it so that it runs indefinitely?

Comment: Works ok for me using JDK7 on Windows 7. The JVM will shut down when all the Threads that are not daemon Thread terminate. Maybe because you don't have a GUI on your OS you don't have any non-daemon Threads running? Check out the Windows.dispose() API and follow the link on "AWT Threading Issues" for more information.

Comment: Working fine for me too using JDK6 on Windows 7.

Comment: Here, when the thread wakes up after 2000 miliseconds, the program terminates. If you remove Thread.sleep(2000), the program does not do anything.

Comment: @camickr I am also using JDK 7_u51 on Windows 7. I tried putting it in a GUI and now it does seem to work fine, interesting... thanks for the input.